# Returning logged in user as a string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am new to C# and not sure if I'm asking this correctly.  I need to return the current logged in user of my app as a string.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName
```

I am using the Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET Web Site template.

```
 Response.Write(System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName);
```

Will not work because it is not of the right "type".  How do I get this value as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName` is a control.

The data item is `Page.User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the username, you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;`

Answer (score 1):

Looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178344(v=vs.80).aspx)? or `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`